# Azure Device Twin Keeps Previous Data

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I am using Azure Device Twin in Azure IOT Hub and this issue is regarding the Device Twin behevior.

I have a DeviceTwin Structure as follows and I am using pure MQTT protocal to publish data into it.

The topic which I used to publish twin data is : $iothub/twin/PATCH/properties/reported/?$rid=c1a12cc8-4168-4e16-a1bb

The payload I sent is :

```
{
  "deviceId": "34aa078e",  
  "properties": {
    "desired": {

    },
    "reported": {
      "notifications": {
        "notification1": {
          "primaryCode": "crprim1",          
          "statusChangeTimestamp": 1507115005615
        },
        "notification2": {
          "primaryCode": "crprim2",          
          "statusChangeTimestamp": 1507117507027
        }
      },
      "location": {

      }      
    }
  }
}
```

All the functionalities are working properly as documented in the DeviceTwin documentation but, I have one clarification to be cleared with respect to the behevior of this DeviceTwin.

When I send a message payload containing one new notification (named as `notificaion3`) through MQTT to update above DeviceTwin, it just add `notification3` into the `notifications` object instead of just replacing entire `notifications` content with `notification3`.

MQTT payload which I sent:

```
{
    "notifications": {
        "notification3": {
          "primaryCode": "crprim3",          
          "statusChangeTimestamp": 1607115005615
        }
    }
}
```

So I will be ultimately have following in the DeviceTwin structure,

```
{
  "deviceId": "34aa078e",  
  "properties": {
    "desired": {

    },
    "reported": {
      "notifications": {
        "notification1": {
          "primaryCode": "crprim1",          
          "statusChangeTimestamp": 1507115005615
        },
        "notification2": {
          "primaryCode": "crprim2",          
          "statusChangeTimestamp": 1507117507027
        },
        "notification3": {
          "primaryCode": "crprim3",          
          "statusChangeTimestamp": 1607115005615
        }
      },
      "location": {

      }      
    }
  }
}
```

Instead of following,

```
{
  "deviceId": "34aa078e",  
  "properties": {
    "desired": {

    },
    "reported": {
      "notifications": {        
        "notification3": {
          "primaryCode": "crprim3",          
          "statusChangeTimestamp": 1607115005615
        }
      },
      "location": {

      }      
    }
  }
}
```

But Device Twin should contains the latest snapshot of a given device and it should not keep the previous data (with respect to a object level). 
Is this the usual behavior of Azure Device Twin ? Or is it some kind of a bug ?

Answer (score 0):

Your device twin behavior based on the above description is not correct. You should see all notifications properties (1,2,3).

You can use 3rd party tools such as MQTTBox Client, iotdevtool.com, [Azure IoT Hub Tester](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1173356/Azure-IoT-Hub-Tester), etc. to see the device twin behavior.

The following screen snippets show this test in my Azure IoT Hub region:

Step 1: adding the *notification1* and *notification2* into the device2 twin reported *notifications* properties:

[image: mqtt1]

Step 2: Get the device2 twin and add the *notification3* into the reported *notifications* properties:

[image: mqtt2]

Step 3: Get the device2 twin to see all *notifications* properties
[image]

Comment: Yes, You are correct, I can see all three notification in this case - which I have clearly stated in "So I will be ultimately have following in the DeviceTwin structure" section above. Actually my real issue is, is this the intended and correct behavior of a device twin - to keep historic data...

Comment: your device twin state for notification should be changed for this      "notification": {
          "id":3,
          "primaryCode": "crprim3",          
          "statusChangeTimestamp": 1607115005615
        }

Answer (score 0):

It is not a bug. For detailed information about this behavior of Azure Device Twin, you can reference [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-device-twins#back-end-operations).

Based on your description, you want to update one reported property continuously. Here we call it as "notification1". So your MQTT payload should like this:

```
{
    "notifications": {
        "notification1": {
          "primaryCode": "crprim3",          
          "statusChangeTimestamp": 1607115005615
        }
    }
}
```

not this:

```
{
    "notifications": {
        "notification3": {
          "primaryCode": "crprim3",          
          "statusChangeTimestamp": 1607115005615
        }
    }
}
```

That is **keeping the property name unchanged** and only update its values.

To remove the other redundant properties you can set its value to NULL like this:

```
{
    "notifications": {
        "notification2": null,
        "notification3": null
    }
}
```

Comment: I think we have a confusion here. What I wanted is to *only* keep notification3 after I sent it. But in this case When I have notification1 and notification2 in the device twin and then once I send new notification called notification3, Device Twin has all three notification. So, I wanted to know whether that is the correct behavior. I am trying to compare this with AWS - Device Shadow in which they only keep the latest value which means in this scenario, at the end it will only have notification3. Tnx.

Comment: @gbids When you use a different property name(notification3) device twin see it as newly added property and this operation is partly updating "notifications", so you will have all three notification here.

Comment: You are correct. I am basically trying to see whether we can get the same behavior as AWS Device Shadow / Thing with Azure. But, seems not.

Comment: @gbids If you only keep one notification you can remove the external "notifications" and just use         "notification": {
          "primaryCode": "crprim3",          
          "statusChangeTimestamp": 1607115005615
        }. Then you can update its value and it will keep the latest data.